# Unknown type name in C?

Tags: c, object

Ok, so I am programming some code in C the program is mainly using pointers I am almost done but have this issue with I keep getting unknown type name on parts of the code. For example in the code below I keep getting ''Unknown type name Pulse'' Essentially it uses objects in C using the tinytimber kernel but Pulse is included in the code.

```
#include "Pulse.h"
typedef struct {
       Object super;
       Pulse *PulserOne;
       Pulse *PulserTwo;
       Pulse *Pulsing;
} GUI;
```

This is another class of the code where pulse is created.

```
typedef struct {
    Object super;
     int pin;   
     int frequency;
     int stored;
     int oldFrequency;
 } Pulse;
# define initPulse(pin, frequency,stored,oldFrequency{initObject(),number, frequency, stored, oldFrequency
```

This is the main class where the objects are declared.

```
Pulse PulserOne = initPulse(4, 0, 0, 0, &p);
Pulse PulserTwo = initPulse(6, 0, 0, 0, &p);
GUI gui = initGUI(&PulserOne, &PulserTwo, &PulserOne);
```

Comment: whats Pulse.h look like?

Comment: @tinkertime Sorry I should have included it right away.

Comment: your example does not seem to be complete. Specifically, ordering matters here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @tinkertime well no? the rest of the 2 structures have the usual codes requiered. Unless you mean the part where the objects are created?

Comment: If this is where you declare `Pulse` then the issue is that the declaration needs to happen before the declaration of `GUI`

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh no it's not like they are 2 seperate classes with objects being created in another class of the programm (I should have been more thoughtful)

Comment: `Pulse PulserOne` declares a *variable* of type `Pulse` - it does not declare the type itself!

Comment: @J.Doe Good that you recognize "I should have included it (Pulse.h) right away", yet the post still does not clearly list the contents of file "Pulse.h".

Comment: @chux actually It does it really isn't anymore than pretty much that the other lines of code are not relevant I added the part that is needed to define the object.

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct {
    Object super;
     int pin;   
     int frequency;
     int stored;
     int oldFrequency;
 } Pulse;`  1) for flexibility and ease of understanding, separate the struct definition from the typedef   2) always include a 'tag' name on a struct definition as most debuggers use the tag name to be able to display the individual fields in the struct

Comment: OT:   The C language does not have `classes` nor `classes with objects`.  You seem to be mixing up C++ and C

Comment: @user3629249 Yeah I have noted I wrote the question very poorly from the start and I am gonna rewrite it later.

Comment: @user3629249 tiny timer kernel makes objects possible in c.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting ''Unknown type name Pulse''

Move the definition of `Pulse` *before* its use. [@UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078704/unknown-type-name-in-c/55078907#comment96904050_55078704)

```
#include "Pulse.h"

// move here.
typedef struct {
    Object super;
    int pin;   
    int frequency;
    int stored;
    int oldFrequency;
 } Pulse;  // Pulse defined here

typedef struct {
    Object super;
    Pulse *PulserOne; // Pulse used here
    Pulse *PulserTwo;
    Pulse *Pulsing;
} GUI;
```

Alternative: Declare the existence of `Pulse`

```
//             v--v--------- Use some name        
typedef struct Fred Pulse;  // Pulse declared here

typedef struct   {
    Object super;
    Pulse *PulserOne; // Pulse used here
    Pulse *PulserTwo;
    Pulse *Pulsing;
} GUId;

typedef struct Fred {
    Object super;
    int pin;
    int frequency;
    int stored;
    int oldFrequency;
 } Pulse;  // Pulse defined here
```

Comment: Well they are in  separate classes I updated how the objects gets declared in the main class.

Comment: @J.Doe When you say "they are in separate classes" are you saying "different files".  "class" usage is unclear here as C does not define _class_.